# How to resize image on mobile devices using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, mobile-website

I am working on a mobile website and I have a div & image inside it like this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">My img tag here</div>
</div>
```

I want to know, how I can resize the image on any phone/tablet without worrying about its resolution, size or orientation. Here, I am looking for the best possible solution based on the above scenarios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple solution using jquery....

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $width = $('#content').width();

    $('#content img').css({
        'max-width': $width,
        'height': 'auto'
    });
});
```

​

Comment: But this will change the resolution of the imgaes I think I was trying some thing like this images doesn't look good in portrait mode

Answer (score 2):

You can use media queries to give CSS attributes depending on the orientation:

```
@media screen and (orientation:portrait) {
    img {
        // css attributes
    }
}

@media screen and (orientation:landscape) {
    img {
        // css attributes
    }
}
```

Or you could do it for screen width:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    img {
        // css attributes
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The above mentioned technique is the most widespread, but as i understand the solution desired shouldn't be dependent about device size, screen resolution or orientation.

I only mention two clever solution, none of them handle this job on CSS:

https://github.com/adamdbradley/foresight.js

http://adaptive-images.com/

The second solution is clever one, because it captures the screen resolution of visitor's device, automatically creates caches and deliver the most appropriated image size of embedded html `<img>` markup.

**Note**: One mention though: this is server dependent solution, and should be used only in PHP code environment.

...and here is a jquery plugin which for the same purposes:
https://github.com/teleject/hisrc